# MySQL Non Sequential ID

Tags: mysql, triggers, auto-increment, last-insert-id

**Challenge:**

Create a method to set "auto_increment" values for tables in a non-sequential way.
The goal is to override the "auto_increment" mechanism and allow the function "LAST_INSERT_ID()" to continue working as expected (returning an INT), so that no changes are needed in software side.

**My Solution**

The method I found is based on an auxiliary table (*unique_id*), that stores values available to be assigned. Values are then selected randomly, and removed from the tables as used. When the table gets empty, a new set of ID's is created.

This example is working as expected, but with one problem.
Tables for the demo:

```
CREATE TABLE `unique_id` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=100;

CREATE TABLE `test_unique_id` (
   `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Defined a stored procedure and a function:

```
DELIMITER $$  
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `UNIQUE_ID_REFILL`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE UNIQUE_ID_REFILL()
BEGIN
   DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
   simple_loop: LOOP
      SET a=a+1;
      INSERT INTO unique_id (id) values(null);
      IF a=100 THEN
         LEAVE simple_loop;
      END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;
END $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `UNIQUE_ID_GET`$$
CREATE FUNCTION UNIQUE_ID_GET()
RETURNS INT(11)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE new_id INT(11);
    DECLARE unique_id_count INT(11);
    SET new_id = 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO unique_id_count FROM unique_id;
    IF unique_id_count=0 THEN
        CALL UNIQUE_ID_REFILL();
    END IF;
    SELECT id INTO new_id FROM unique_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
    DELETE FROM unique_id WHERE id = new_id;
    RETURN new_id;
END $$
```

Created a Trigger on the destination table (*test_unique_id*):

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_unique_id__unique_id BEFORE INSERT ON test_unique_id
  FOR EACH ROW 
    SET NEW.id = UNIQUE_ID_GET();
```

The solution is getting the random ID's as expected:

```
INSERT INTO test_unique_id(name) VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C');
```

Creates the rows:

```
id   name
154  'A'
129  'B'
173  'C'
```

**The Problem**

The main problem is that LAST_INSERT_ID() stops working... and the software side is broken:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
0
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? or any other different approach to the challenge?

Thank you very much.

Comment: But why....? :-(

Comment: What was the issue that caused you to do this? Maybe there is an easier approach to solve the original issue that you had. I will say that don't try and play with the id processing. that is looked after by the database. imo, It will end in tears if you try and mess with it. .

Comment: The motivation behind all this is the fact that our company is using a 3rd party software, where we cannot change most behaviors. The fact that some objects have a sequential ID reveals some information (via browser URL's) on the quantity of existing objects and is considered a relevant information leak.